# query four tables returning all the records from table 1 and only records from the other tables where a match is found

Tags: mysql

I have a need to get all the records from table t1 and records from t2, t3 and t4 where there is a match on the columns "DeviceID19" and "BoardID".
At the moment my query only returns one record from t1.

```
SELECT
c.DisplayDescription, 
c.DisplayID,
COUNT(c.RecordID) AS RC, 
c.BoardID, 
h.messageCount, 
h.deviceID, 
h.deviceDesc, 
h.record_ID, 
h.DeviceID19,
h.BoardOverride AS HBO, 
b.RecordID, 
b.RoomName, 
b.MainBoardOverride, 
p.RecordID AS SignageRecordID, 
p.BoardID, 
p.SignageOnOff, 
p.RoomFromStamp, 
p.RoomToStamp 
FROM t1 AS c 
Left Join t2 AS h ON c.BoardID = h.DeviceID19 AND h.caseID = 'EXBHX' 
Left Join t3 AS b ON b.BoardID = c.BoardID AND h.caseID = 'EXBHX' 
Left Join t4 AS p ON h.DeviceID19 = p.DeviceID19 AND h.caseID = 'EXBHX' 
WHERE h.DeviceID19 IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY h.messageCount DESC, c.DisplayID ASC
```

Comment: Remove the condition `WHERE h.DeviceID19 IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @forpas Hi, I did and it still only returns one record. It should be returning three record from the t1 table. But thanks for looking at the issue.

Comment: Are you sure that all the joins are left joins? If they are then you should get 3 rows. So posts sample data or better create a demo fiddle to clarify here: https://www.db-fiddle.com

Comment: @forpas  Hi, I have tried my best to create a demo fiddle but for some reason db-fiddle would not allow the GROUP BY statement in the query. The demo is at: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r3HPeqSRXK8SV5d5BKhBzE/1

Comment: What is the problem with the results? If you remove the condition `h.DeviceID19 IS NOT NULL` you get results for 3 displayids of t1.